# Why the matrix element grows with energy in this case?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, ward-identity

Consider the QED with massive photons:
$$
\mathcal{L} = g\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\psi A_{\mu}, \quad g = \text{const}
$$
Because of the current conservation, the contribution of the longitudinal polarization behaving as $\epsilon^{L}_{\mu}\sim p_{\mu}/m_{A}$ in the high-energy limit $\sqrt{s}\gg m_{A}$ is canceled in any order of the perturbation theory -- this is what we know as the Ward identities. In particular, for the Compton scattering case, $A+\psi \to A+\psi$ the cancellation in the leading order of the perturbation theory occurs when summing over two diagrams, one in the $t$-channel and another one in the $u$-channel.

Now, consider the following Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L} = g\bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\psi A^{\mu} + g'\bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\chi X^{\mu} + \text{h.c.},
$$
where $X^{\mu}$ represents electrically charged particle, and $\psi,\chi$ are particles that have the same mass and different electric charges. Both currents
$$
J_{\mu} = \bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\psi, \quad \mathcal{J}_{\mu} = \bar{\psi}\gamma_{\mu}\chi
$$
are conserved. Naively, I expected that the leading-order matrix element for the analog of the Compton scattering, $\psi + A \to \chi + X$, should not depend on the longitudinal polarizations of $A,X$. But this is not the case, as now there is only one diagram for the process, and the cancellation does not occur.

How to interpret this qualitatively, why the classical current conservation does not lead to the analog of Ward identities in this case, unlike the case of QED?

Comment: Comment to the post (v4): 1. Massive photons? With what mechanism is gauge invariance maintained? 2. Should $\bar{\psi}$ be $\bar{\chi}$ in various places?

Comment: @Qmechanic : this may be for instance the Stueckelberg mechanism. Another idea is that we do not care about the gauge invariance itself, only about the unitarity, which in absence of the gauge invariance is still preserved in QED-like theories because of the current conservation.

Comment: I am puzzled: ignoring the local U(1) symmetry and focussing on the global one, the g' trilinear interaction you wrote imposes *another* term on the "electric current", your first conserved current, the neutral one, at the very least! Your second, calligraphic,  one, is a charged current, obviously, and you must specify its non-commutativity w.r.t. the first.

Comment: @CosmasZachos : why should I specify this? How does it translate to the violation of the Ward identities despite the classical current conservation?

Comment: I already indicated $J_\mu$ is not conserved, as written. It must contain terms gauge-rotating $\chi$ and $X_\mu$, and its conservation is predicated on elaborate equations of motion for ***all*** $\psi,\chi, X_\mu$. The charged current  $\cal J$ cannot be conserved for similar reasons: it destroys a $\chi$ in favor of a $\psi$. Write down your gauge invariant action and argue for its invariance. Algebraic closure of charges is required by consistency of this invariance, as you have learned. Do the drill!